# Connect to ESP8266 WiFI (softAP) with an OnePlus 6 not working

Tags: android, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, oneplusthree

I have a problem connecting my OnePlus 6 to the WiFi access point my ESP8266 makes. I use the `WiFi.softAP()` function and I have made a small web-application which is loaded upon visiting the standard IP `192.168.4.1` from a web-browser. It works fine with any device (laptop, iPhone, Samsung Galaxy etc.), however, when using a OnePlus smartphone the browser does not seem to be able to load the page. I have tried multiple browsers without luck.

I had the same issue with an ESP32 a few months ago, and it seems to only affect OnePlus devices. How can this be, is there some WiFi setting in OnePlus that blocks the data coming from the ESP8266? It is frustrating to keep borrowing other peoples phones for testing!

Comment: I would suggest watching the ESP8266 console with the debug level at 3 (`mos config-set debug.level=3`).  When your OnePlus tries to view the webpage, the mos `http-server` should give you some useful error message.

Comment: Also check that your OnePlus can join the same subnet and ping `192.168.4.1`.  And check that `wifi.ap.max_connections` is not too low.